# a href=mailto: - как заставить работать?

Tags: html, sendmail

Доброго всем здравия!
Недавно заметил (давно им не пользовался), что тег

```
<a href="mailto:onvillage@grandfather.ru">отправить письмо</a>
```

в современных браузерах отключили (Opera, Chrome).
Как это победить? Не прибегая к PHP (так как сайты визитки, без PHP)

Comment: У меня три современных браузера. Во всех работает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Покажите браузер, где это отключили?

Comment: Chrome фурычит

Comment: У ТС видимо либо какой-то плагин стоит блокирующий, либо еще что-то.

Comment: [test](mailto:test@example.com)

Comment: Chrome не фурычит

Comment: А The Bat может влиять отрицательно?
Раньше выскакивал почтовый клиент (thebat) он и установлен, в нём почему-то ассоциации не активны.
Попробую заменить MAPI32.dll

Comment: С использованием mailto-ссылок без обфускации [**повышается возможность получения спама**](http://superuser.com/a/235965/572069). Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказывается по умолчанию в Windows 7 нет почтового клиента, как был в ХР OutLook Express (как-то так он назывался).
Снос The Bat'a и установка Windows Live Mail немного исправила ситуацию.
Но как всегда... Это же Windows!!!
Кодировку charset=Windows-1251 Свою же(!!!) не воспринимает в коде:

```
<a href="mailto:zlaya@vbudke.tut?subject=письмо%20бла-бла-бла%20с%20сайта&Body=Здравствуйте.%0D%0AХочу%20заказать%20у%20Вас%20тыры-пыры%20трали-вали%20%22Наименование%22.%20В%20количестве%20(%20)шт.%20Мои%20контакты:" target="_self">
```

Ну да ладно. Дело стронулось с мёртвой точки...
Извиняюсь за такое применение (a href), но клиент хочет бесплатный (точнее не может позволить платный) хостинг.
P.S. Как же всё "проще" становиться с новыми Виндовсами ;)

Answer (score 4):

Google Chrome может пытаться обрабатывать `mailto:` через GMail. Если вы не пользуетесь GMail'ом из Chrome, то он не знает, что делать. См. `chrome://settings/handlers - GMail`. У меня под `Mac OS X 10.8.2`, `Chrome 24.0.1312.56` открывает стандартное почтовое приложение `Mail`. Все настройки по умолчанию.

В общем, дело может быть только в настройках браузера, и веб-мастеру ничего с этим не поделать. Если только попытаться отлавливать негативный возврат с клика по `mailto:` и как альтернативу предлагать форму обр. связи.

Comment: Форма обратной связи это хорошо, но хостинг бесплатный (голый HTML)

Comment: [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) — вот напр. облачная платформа, где можно поднять приложение на PHP с кучей плюшек вроде базы данных, memcached и пр. — в рамках бесплатного тарифа. Если сайт не дико посещаемый, мощности хватит за глаза.

Answer (score 0):

Все довольно таки банально просто! В виндовсе с какого то перепуга сбиваются настройки программ по умолчанию, добавь приложение "почта" или outlook как приложение по умолчанию Панель управления --> Программы --> Задание программ по умолчанию. Из списка выбираешь программу для работы с почтой, после этого mailto будет работать.